# Unity C# Base/Child variable call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the code below, The player will click on a item within the inventory, and the code's purpose is IF the item is a item(base) type of food(type of item), then I want to call a method within the Food script. I want to be able to call a function from within another class passing in a float from (food).

```
public void UseItem(){
    if (item != null) {
        if (item is Food) {//checking when i click to see if item is of type food
            PHH.Heal(hpToHealWhenAte);//here is where the problem is
        } else {
            item.Use ();
        }
    }
}
```

Food

```
public class Food : Item {
    public float healthHealedOnUse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast `item` to `Food` type then call the function with the `healthHealedOnUse` variable: `PPH.Heal(((Food)item).healthHealedOnUse)`

This is called Down-Casting (casting from a base-class to a child-class)

```
public void UseItem(){
        if (item != null) {
            if (item is Food) { //checking if item is Food type..
                PHH.Heal(((Food)item).healthHealedOnUse); //Cast item to Food..
            } else {
                item.Use ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Another way of casting would also look like:  `(item as Food).healthHealedOnUse`..

The `((Food)item)` (C-Style cast) would throw an exception if item cannot be casted to Food.. `(item as Food)` as style cast is known as a safe-cast and will return null if item cannot be casted to Food.

Comment: ok, so when i do this, its effecting all item using the food script, like for instance, I have 2 potatos, and when i use one, its taking a use off of both of them? What could you do to make them 2 different instances?                          [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Food Item", menuName = "Inventory/Food")]
public class Food : Item {
 public float healthHealedOnUse;
 public int uses;

}

Comment: What? @BrandonG; That's not possible unless the instances are holding static variables. If you have ONE potato with its own health variable (non-static), then changing it won't affect others. Something else is going on in your code.. Check to make sure you're actually only using one.. Maybe give each potato an ID and see which one is being used..

Answer (score 0):

## Method Overrides

Your base Item class:

```
public class Item {
    public virtual void Use(Player PHH) {
    }
}
```

And your Food class:

```
public class Food : Item {
    public float healthHealedOnUse;

    public override void Use(Player PHH) {
        PHH.Heal(healthHealedOnUse); 
    }
}
```

Your UseItem method:

```
public void UseItem(){
    if (item != null) {
        item.Use(PHH);
    }
}
```